# Are there "rules" for Ruby syntactic sugar?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning the basics of Ruby (just starting out), and I came across the [`Hash.[]` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_hash.html#Hash._ob_cb). It was introduced with

```
a = ["foo", 1, "bar", 2]
=> ["foo", 1, "bar", 2]
Hash[*a]
=> {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2}
```

With a little thought, I figured out that `Hash[*a]` is equivalent to `Hash.[](*a)` or `Hash.[] *a`. My question is why that's the case. What is it that lets you put the `*a` inside the square brackets, and is there some kind of rule for where and when else "it" can be used?

**Edit:** My wording seems to be causing some confusion. I'm not asking about the array expansion. I get that. My question is basically: if `[]` is a method name, why is it okay to put arguments inside the brackets? It seems almost--but not quite--like saying that if you have a method `Foo.dood`, and you wanted to pass the string `"hey"` to it, then you could write `Foo.do"hey"od`.

Comment: I see lots of answers focusing on `*a` in a method invocation. However, it would be nice to see other productions addressed, such as why `[1,*a]` works "as expected" (which yields a different result than `[1, a]`) and why `[*a,1]` is invalid. It would also be nice to see how "splat" relates to assignment and how it can/does interact with Ruby's assignment-decomposition... perhaps arguably a different SO question entirely ;-) It would be *really nice* if there was a semi-formal ruby specification. Links to quasi-specifications would make answers better.

Comment: @pst: good questions. If you ask a new SO question about it, post the link here so I can follow it.

Comment: note that the usual way use it is by sending an array of pairs: Hash[[[key1, value1], [key2, value2]]]

Comment: @pst: There is a kind of semi-formal Ruby specification: http://rubyspec.org/. Also `[*a, 1]` works in 1.9, as do multiple splats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple methods that ruby lets you call in a special way. These are the `[]` as you mentioned, the `+`, `-`, `==` and the like as someone else mentioned. Another important example are methods of the form `something=(value)` which can be called with `object.something = value` and allow you to create accessors.

Edit:

Fun fact 1: if you define a `+` method you get `+=` for free.

Fun fact 2: if you define a `<=>` you get all comparison methods, courtesy of [Comparable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Comparable.html)

Comment: So is there a list somewhere of this "special" stuff?

Comment: There is a list of operators that can be overridden [here](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#28)

Answer (score 4):

`Hash["a", "b", "c", "d"]` is equivalent to `Hash.[]("a", "b", "c", "d")`. Almost everything in Ruby is a method call. `5 + 5` is equivalent to `5.+(5)`.

Given `a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]` `Hash[*a]` is equivalent to `Hash["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, which in turn is equivalent to `Hash.[]("a", "b", "c", "d")`. Similarly, `foo(*a)` is equivalent to `foo("a", "b", "c", "d")` This is called the explode operator, and allows sending an array to a method and have each item in the array count as one argument to the method, instead of sending the array to the method as the first argument.

---

To specifically answer your update, there's nothing special that lets you put `*a` inside the brackets. The brackets is just sugar for a normal method call. The only "special" thing here is that you can send `*a` to any method.

Comment: So what are [all] the places where splat-expansion is allowed? (There is at least one more not relating to method invocation AFAIK.)

Comment: Update? I haven't updated anything. So are you saying that anywhere that square brackets occur in Ruby as a method name, you can use the brackets instead of parentheses to contain the argument list? I.e any old method `Foo.[]` taking arguments a, b, and c could be written as `Foo[a, b, c]`? Is that just a magical language feature?

Comment: That's correct. A method named [] can be invoked with the `my_obj[foo]` sugar. A method named []= can be invoked with `my_obj[foo] = bar`. This transforms to `my_obj.[]=(foo, bar)`. This is what powers the syntax of `Hash` instances. There's also `Dir["glob pattern"]`, which transforms to `Dir.[]("glob pattern")`.

Comment: Okay, so what is it that makes that work, and/or is there a list of these special method names somewhere?

Comment: I don't know how MRI implements this in C. I don't know about a list either.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Ruby's syntax is defined in parse.y for YARV Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The `*<Array>` method tells ruby not to take the array as array, but to use the 'expanded' array.

Example:

```
def test(*argv)
  p argv
end

a = [1,2,3]
test(a) #-> [[1, 2, 3]]
test(*a) #-> [1, 2, 3]
```

With  `test(a)` the array a is the *one and only* parameter.

With  `test(*a)` a is used as a list of parameters.

---

In your case

```
a = ["foo", 1, "bar", 2]
Hash[*a]
```

is similar to

```
Hash["foo", 1, "bar", 2]
```

`Hash[*a]` would be

```
Hash[["foo", 1, "bar", 2]]
```

Comment: Right, but where is this allowed or not allowed? (e.g. what are the production rules?)

Comment: Depend on the method where you use it. `a` is one array, `*a` is a list of parameters. So, the question is not, is `*a` allowed, but: Do I need an array as parameter, or do I need a parameter list.

Comment: My question isn't about the array expansion. It's about the `[]` method and specifically why it's okay to put arguments inside those brackets.