# Defining an attr_writer method def color=(new_color). Why the =?

Tags: ruby

In order to give write access to an instance variable, we use `attr_writer`, or define an accessor method manually by:

```
class Car
  attr_reader :color

  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
  end

  def color=(new_color)
    @color = new_color
  end
end
```

Why the `=`? I thought it was just a convention. If I use `*` instead of `=`, it doesn't work.

Where can I find information on how this method is built internally in Ruby?

Comment: Don't have a answer for how it's built internally, but this is special "syntactic sugar". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705693/are-there-rules-for-ruby-syntactic-sugar

Comment: There are many Ruby methods that end with an equals sign. Often, they are one of a pair of methods that have the same name except one has an equals sign tacked onto the end. The one with the equals sign is used to set a value, the other returns a value...

Comment: ...Some built-in examples are [String#\[\]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), [Hash#\[\]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D), [Array#\[\]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) and five more in the class [IO](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html).

Comment: Consider `String#[]` and suppose `str = 'cat'`. We could use this method in the conventional Ruby way: `str = 'cat'; str.[]=(1,'u'); str #=> "cut"`. The presence of the equals sign, however, means that we can write it more conveniently as `str[1] = 'u'; str #=> 'cut'`. This is what @maxpleaner means by *syntactic sugar*. Note that this does not apply only to built-in methods; you can use the *sugar* form for your own methods whose names end with an equals sign.

Comment: Methods ending with `=` indicate _assignment methods_ because they can be invoked like an assignment (so we have `car.color = 'green'` instead of `car.set_color('green')` in Ruby). The `=` is an essential part of the method's name, it cannot be omitted. See the documentation for [method names](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Names).

Answer (score 0):

It is intuitive since `attr_writer` is a setter method and since variable assignment is done in ruby with `my_string = 'foo'` for example, it makes sense.

If you want the source see  https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_writer